# fast multiplication of power of a matrix by a vector

Tags: matrix-multiplication

I'm interested in computing of the product $M^n v$, where $M$ is an $m\times m$ matrix (over a semiring) and $v$ is column-vector, with the smallest number of multiplications in the underlying semiring and in the regime of $n=\Theta(m)$.

If we first compute $M^n$ using fast exponentiation, this would take $\Theta(\log n)$ matrix multiplications, totaling in $\Theta(m^3\log n)$ semiring multiplications (assuming naive matrix multiplication).

On the other hand, if we just iteratively compute $M^k v$ for $k=1,2,\dots,n$, each time multiplying a vector by $M$, then it'd take us $\Theta(m^2n)$ semiring multiplications.

So, fast exponentiation appears to be useless. Is there any other way to speed up things here?

Comment: Is $M$ a [diagonalizable matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix)? Or maybe can be converted to [Jordan normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form)? In that case, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/910635/power-of-a-matrix-given-its-jordan-form) might help you.

Comment: @nirshahar: Diagonalizable matrices exist over fields, in my case matrix is over a semiring, which in fact contains no invertible elements except the multiplicative identity.